# Derivative continuity

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Suppose $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ is an open interval with infinitely many points and $h:I\to \mathbb{R}$ is a function. If $h'(x)>0$ for some $x \in I$, then show that there is an open set $U$ containing x so that $\forall t \in U \cap I$\ $x $ we have $\frac{h(t)-h(x)}{t-x}\geq0.$ Bonus find a polynomial function strictly increasing who's first derivative is not always positive. Does it contradict the statement above.

I've tried messing around with the definition of continuity and using the FTC2 to write f' as a function and then show that if it is  positive at one point there must be some $\delta$ neighborhood where $F(x) = f'(x)$ is positive. But I don't seem to be getting anything meaningful. For the bonus I know $x^3$ works and I don't think it breaks the statement because is says $\geq 0$ not >$0$.

Answer (score 1):

If there are points $t$ arbitrarily close to $x$ such that $\frac{h(t)-h(x)}{t-x}<0$ then it follows from the definition of limit that $\lim_{t\to x}\frac{h(t)-h(x)}{t-x}\leqslant0$. This is impossible, since $\lim_{t\to x}\frac{h(t)-h(x)}{t-x}=f'(x)>0$.

Concerning the bonus question, what about $x\mapsto x^3$?

Comment: Omg this is it I think

Comment: What if $\frac{h(t)-h(x)}{t-x}>0 $ does this proof still hold? just wondering.

Comment: Yes, since $\frac{h(t)-h(x)}{t-x}>0\implies\frac{h(t)-h(x)}{t-x}\geqslant0$.